# Unable to Compile SDL Release Build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, sdl, sdl-2

despite the fact that I can compile a debug release fine, I'm unable to compile a release build. My linkage settings are fine yet I'm getting these strange errors.

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Main.cpp C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\LINK  ForgedMemories
Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_GetTicks C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\BattleManager.obj ForgedMemories
Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Sound.obj ForgedMemories
Error   4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Mix_PlayChannelTimed C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Sound.obj ForgedMemories
Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_RWFromFile   C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Sound.obj ForgedMemories
Error   6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Mix_LoadWAV_RW   C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Sound.obj ForgedMemories
Error   7   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Mix_Quit C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Sound.obj ForgedMemories
Error   8   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Mix_FreeChunk    C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Sound.obj ForgedMemories
Error   9   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_GetError C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Sound.obj ForgedMemories
Error   10  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Mix_OpenAudio    C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Sound.obj ForgedMemories
Error   11  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_GetMouseState    C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\EventManager.obj  ForgedMemories
Error   12  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _TTF_RenderText_Shaded    C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Font_Setup.obj    ForgedMemories
Error   13  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_RenderCopy   C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Font_Setup.obj    ForgedMemories
Error   14  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Font_Setup.obj    ForgedMemories
Error   15  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _TTF_RenderText_Blended   C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Font_Setup.obj    ForgedMemories
Error   16  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _TTF_OpenFont C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Font_Setup.obj    ForgedMemories
Error   17  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _TTF_CloseFont    C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Font_Setup.obj    ForgedMemories
Error   18  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _TTF_Init C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Font_Setup.obj    ForgedMemories
Error   19  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_QueryTexture C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Font_Setup.obj    ForgedMemories
Error   20  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_FreeSurface  C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Font_Setup.obj    ForgedMemories
Error   21  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_GetKeyboardState C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Keyboard.obj  ForgedMemories
Error   22  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_PumpEvents   C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Keyboard.obj  ForgedMemories
Error   23  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_DestroyWindow    C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Setup.obj ForgedMemories
Error   24  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_CreateWindow C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Setup.obj ForgedMemories
Error   25  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_PollEvent    C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Setup.obj ForgedMemories
Error   26  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_DestroyRenderer  C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Setup.obj ForgedMemories
Error   27  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_RenderPresent    C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Setup.obj ForgedMemories
Error   28  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_RenderClear  C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Setup.obj ForgedMemories
Error   29  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_CreateRenderer   C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\SDL_Setup.obj ForgedMemories
Error   30  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_DestroyTexture   C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\Sprite.obj    ForgedMemories
Error   31  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IMG_LoadTexture  C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\ForgedMemoriesV2.3\Sprite.obj    ForgedMemories
Error   32  error LNK1120: 31 unresolved externals  C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\ForgedMemories\Release\ForgedMemories.exe   ForgedMemories
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add SDL2.lib and SDL2main.lib to Linker -> Input:Addition Dependencies for release configuration?

Comment: Re-check the input to the linker and then take a look at MSDN: [Linker Tools Error LNK2001](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6xx1b1z%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by not having set the library input for both configurations, a commonly made mistake. You just need to add the required libraries to the Release configuration. This also applies to the header file include directories

[image]

Comment: This has fixed it! I can't thank you enough Zammalad, now I can give my release of my RPG to people :)